# Changing navbar text color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors

I'm working with Bootstrap navbar and I want to change colour of one of the links. I can easily change colour of all links with the code below, but i need to change just one.

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
color: red;
}
```

and HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Let's say I want to change colour of the **Login** link to red. How to do this without changing **About** link colour at the same time and what's the rules of changing style of one element instead of all in nested elements like lists in navbar?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an Attribute Selector:

```css
a[href="/login"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `text-danger` class to your required tag to change color.

Bootstrap provides some different theme colors through classes. Go through the document [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/color/)

You required for `login`. Hence added `text-danger` to that respected `<a href='/login'>Login</a>` tag.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-danger" href="/login">Login</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**Using `:n-th-of-type()`**

If you have similar tags as present here and want to change only selected ones then you can use this method. You can see [n-th-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), [nth-last-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type)

```
li:nth-of-type(3) a{  // It will select third li a element
  color: red
}

li:nth-of-type(2n) a{  // It will select even li a element like 2nd, 4th, ..
  color: red
}

li:nth-of-type(2n+1) a{  // It will select odd li a element like 1st, 3rd, ..
  color: red
}
```

Comment: That works, but what if I want to change another style element separately? Attribute selector suggested by Sebastian doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @JustasG There are many ways and it depends on situation. You can also use `li:nth-of-type(3) a{ color: red; }` in above example.

Comment: @JustasG updated the answer. I hope it will clear your solution